# In xml doc, can I insert a reference to a method group? How?

Tags: c#, .net, documentation, documentation-generation

In C#, I can attach documentation for properties, methods, events, and so on,
directly in the code using [XML Documentation Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx).

I know how to insert a reference to a particular method:

```
<see cref="MethodName(TypeForArg1, TypeForArg2..)"/>
```

Is there a way to insert a reference to a *method group*?  Where I've got multiple overloads of the same method name...

I tried

```
<see cref="M:MethodName"/>
```

..but that did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently there is no way to do this.

Comment: Still true in 2023 using VS 2022.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that this behavior occurs in Visual Studio 2012-2022:

```
<see cref="MethodName"/>
```

Will generate a warning:

> Ambiguous reference in cref attribute: 'MethodName'. Assuming '…', but could have also matched other overloads including '…'.

But adding an `M:` in front get's rid of the warning:

```
<see cref="M:MethodName"/>
```

Comment: This [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/processing-the-xml-file) indicates that the "M" prefix is valid in the generated XML, but I'm not sure that means this syntax is supported for method groups in particular. Do documentation tools like Sandcastle interpret these method-group references without error?

Comment: The in-VS experience (hovering over the symbol being documented) just shows the method name inline with no special markup (i.e. might as well replace the `see` with just the method group name itself.

Answer (score 0):

[This is now supported in Sandcastle.](https://ewsoftware.github.io/XMLCommentsGuide/html/16cdb957-a35b-4c17-bf5e-ea511b0218e3.htm#Examples)

To reference a method group, the following syntax is required:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reference to a method group with two items:
/// <see cref="O:Full.Declaring.Namespace.TypeName.Foo"/>
/// </summary>
void Foo() { }
void Foo(int x) { }
```

Note that this syntax does still have some limitations, as described [this C# language feature request](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/320).

- The syntax is not validated during build. Errors made while typing are not reported until if/when Sandcastle Help File Builder processes the comments.
- The syntax **only** works if there are more than one method with the same name.
- There is no syntax highlighting or editor support for this syntax.